# Java method that can't be callable but can be overridden

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, visibility

If I don't want that a method on my class can be called, I just make it private.

But if I want to allow that method to be overridden, I have to make it protected

Is it possible to have a method on an abstract class that can't be called but can be overridden? (I guess not, but is there any workaround?)

Use case:

```
abstract class Super {

  protected void finalize() {

  }

  public final void doThings() {
   // do stuff
   finalize();
  }
}
```

and whoever wanted to extend the class:

```
class Sub extends Super {

  @Override
  protected void finalize() {
    closeSockets();
    alertSomeone();
  }

}
```

But I don't want other classes calling `mySub.finalize()`;

Comment: ***can't be called but can be overridden***.... I dont get it, you want to override a method that you can not call???

Comment: What would the purpose be for an overridable but not callable function? It kind of defeats the purpose. Maybe you should take a second look at your design.

Comment: OP wants a method, that is called inside the class, like a `private`, but also overridable... I think it is not possible, as if any class can see it to overrid, it can see it to call also...

Comment: the method would be used in the abstract class in a template pattern.

Comment: edited the question with the use case @scrappedcola

Comment: This whole thing has a bad smell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overwriting a method, the sub-class may provide the super-class with a Runnable which contains the code to be executed. You could do something like this:

```
public class Super {

    private final Runnable subClassCode;

    public Super(Runnable finalizeCode) {
        subClassCode = finalizeCode;
    }

    public final void doThings() {
        // do stuff
        subClassCode.run();
    }

}

public class Sub extends Super {

    public Sub() {
        super(() -> {
            // code to be executed in doThings()
        });
    }

}
```

You dont need to set the Runnable instance in the constructor. You may also give access to a protected setFinalizeCode(Runnable) method but that method could also be called by other classes within the same package as Super.